# How to convert utf-32 code like U+20000 into character in VBA?

Tags: vba, character, utf-32

If `s` contains `20000` and `j` is `Len(s)` the following

```
Dim b(1 To 8)
b() = ChrW("&H" & Mid$(s, 1, j - 4)) & ChrW("&H" & Mid$(s, j - 3))
```

does not work. It returns 2 characters while U+20000 is a single.

Comment: It produced two characters because you _told_ it to produce two characters: `ChrW$("&H2") & ChrW$("&H0000")`.  A beter question might be 'does VBA support utf-32'

Answer (score 2):

Better code is based on here example: http://www.vbforums.com/archive/index.php/t-526476.html

```
Public Function ChrU(UCode As String) As String

Dim CharCode As Long
CharCode = Val("&H00" & Right(UCode, Len(UCode) - 2))

If CharCode < 0 Then
    CharCode = CharCode + 65536
End If

Dim lngChar As Long
If CharCode >= 0 Then
    If CharCode < &HD800& Then
        ChrU = ChrW$(CharCode)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf CharCode < &HDC00& Then
        ' UTF-16 surrogates are invalid in UTF-32
    ElseIf CharCode < &HFFFF& Then
        ChrU = ChrW$(CharCode)
        Exit Function
    ElseIf CharCode < &H10FFFF Then
        lngChar = CharCode - &H10000
        ChrU = ChrW$(&HD800& Or (lngChar \ 1024)) & ChrW$(&HDC00& Or (lngChar And &H3FF&))
        Exit Function
    End If
End If
Err.Raise 5
End Function
```

Comment: You should have posted this as an edit to your question, not as a answer.

Comment: This is an answer, the code works for for long hexstrings, I have tested it and use it. If I found some bugs then will post them here.

Comment: You may want to phrase it better as an answer. Right now it seems more like an addition to your question than an answer to it.

Comment: The surrogate range is defined from `&HD800&` to `&HDFFF&`. You are only excluding high surrogates, but you should also exclude the [low surrogates](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+DC00). To do that, just replace `ElseIf CharCode < &HDC00& Then` with `ElseIf CharCode < &HE000& Then`. Also, instead of `ElseIf CharCode < &HFFFF& Then`, it should of course be `ElseIf CharCode < &H10000 Then`. Otherwise great code, very good performance!